# Addition of every 5 numbers continuously in an array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have an array of numbers in the codes shown below.

```
$result_data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);

$arrayCount = count($result_data);

for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++)
{
    if ($x%5==0)
    {
        $sum = $result_data[0] + $result_data[1] + $result_data[2] + $result_data[3] + $result_data[4];
        echo json_encode($sum);
        echo ("\n");
    }       

}
```

And I got the result of:

```
15 15 15 15
```

Actually I wanted the results to be the sum of every 5 numbers in the array continuously and would expect the result to be:

```
15 40 65 90
```

Anyone knows how to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce all of that code to:

```
$result_data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
echo implode('\n', array_map('array_sum', array_chunk($result_data, 5))),'\n';
```

Which outputs:

```
15
40
65
90
```

See the man pages for:

- [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)
- [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [array_sum](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)
- [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of referecing `$result_data[1]`, `$result_data[2]`, `$result_data[3]` etc you need to base the ID off your current `$x` value, like this

`$sum = $result_data[$x] + $result_data[$x+1] + $result_data[$x+2] + $result_data[$x+3] + $result_data[$x+4]`

### A different approach

I would probably approach this in a different manner, continuously adding the values as I went along, and outputting the current total when I got to each fifth number, something like this:

```
$result_data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);

$arrayCount = count($result_data);

$subtotal = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++)
{
    $subtotal += $result_data[$x];
    if ($x%5==0)
    {
        echo json_encode($subtotal);
        echo ("\n");
        $subtotal = 0;.
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result_data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);

$arrayCount = count($result_data);

for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++)
{
    if ($x%5==0)
    {
        $sum = $result_data[$x] + $result_data[$x+1] + $result_data[$x+2] + $result_data[$x+3] + $result_data[$x+4];
        echo json_encode($sum);
        echo ("\n");
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$sum = $result_data[0] + $result_data[1] + $result_data[2] + $result_data[3] + $result_data[4]
```

you probably wanted

```
$sum = $result_data[$x] + $result_data[$x+1] + $result_data[$x+2] + $result_data[$x+3] + $result_data[$x+4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$sum = $result_data[$x] + $result_data[$x+1] + $result_data[$x+2] + $result_data[$x+3] + $result_data[$x+4]
```

instead of:

```
$sum = $result_data[0] + $result_data[1] + $result_data[2] + $result_data[3] + $result_data[4];
```

since you've assigned `$x` inside your `for` loop.

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/f2u5U0)**

Answer (score 0):

### <kbd>[Working demo](http://codepad.org/lwtmcrpP)</kbd>

```
$result_data = range(1,20);
foreach($result_data as $key=>$value){
    if($value%5==0){
        echo $value+$result_data[$key-1]+$result_data[$key-2]
             +$result_data[$key-3]+$result_data[$key-4]."\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output :

15

40

65

90